# Bridge startup error connecting to Zookeeper

Tags: apache-zookeeper, corda

Just getting the following error trying to setup the Bridge component using Zookeeper, according to the steps described in https://docs.corda.r3.com/website/releases/3.1/bridge-configuration-file.html?highlight=zookeeper.

```
> java -jar corda-bridgeserver-3.1.jar
BridgeSupervisorService: active = false
[ERROR] 20:59:31-0300 [main-EventThread] imps.EnsembleTracker.processConfigData - Invalid config event received: {server.1=10.102.32.104:2888:3888:participant, version=100000000, server.3=10.102.32.108:2888:3888:participant, server.2=10.102.32.107:2888:3888:participant}
[ERROR] 20:59:32-0300 [main-EventThread] imps.EnsembleTracker.processConfigData - Invalid config event received: {server.1=10.102.32.104:2888:3888:participant, version=100000000, server.3=10.102.32.108:2888:3888:participant, server.2=10.102.32.107:2888:3888:participant}
```

My `bridge.conf`:

```
bridgeMode = BridgeInner
outboundConfig {
    artemisBrokerAddress = "10.102.32.97:10010"
    alternateArtemisBrokerAddresses = [ "10.102.32.98:10010" ]
}
bridgeInnerConfig {
    floatAddresses = ["10.102.32.103:12005", "10.102.32.105:12005"]
    expectedCertificateSubject = "CN=Float Local,O=Local Only,L=London,C=GB"
    customSSLConfiguration {
           keyStorePassword = "bridgepass"
           trustStorePassword = "trustpass"
           sslKeystore = "./bridgecerts/bridge.jks"
           trustStoreFile = "./bridgecerts/trust.jks"
           crlCheckSoftFail = true
    }
}
haConfig {
    haConnectionString = "zk://10.102.32.104:2181,zk://10.102.32.107:2181,zk://10.102.32.108:2181"
}
networkParametersPath = ./network-parameters
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error is harmless. It indicates that the Dockerised Zookeeper has bad IP addresses, so when the Apache Curator is sent the dynamic topology, some checks fail. It does not invalidate the static configuration and everything should work fine.

Note that as of Corda Enterprise 3.2, you must use the Zookeeper version that is compatible with the Apache Curator library, which is 3.5.3-beta, and NOT the latest version.

Comment: Thanks Joe. Indeed, it's working. Just an observation, the Zookeeper is not dockerized. I'll check the IP configuration.